# Python: namespaces, error: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

This code works as expected:

```
    def my_fun():
        a = b
        a = 5
        print a

    b = 2
    my_fun()
    print b
```

And I get:

```
5
2
```

But if I do:

```
    def my_fun():
        a = b
        a = 5
        b = 1
        print a

    b = 2
    my_fun()
    print b
```

I do get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment`

What happens here ? Although `b` is visible to the function, I cannot change it inside the function ?

Comment: Add `global b` in the first line of `my_fun`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `b = 1`, the interpreter starts treating `b` as a local variable. If you want to assign the global variable `b`, you have to put the statement `global b` at the start of your function.

```
def my_fun():
    global b
    # do stuff

b = 2
my_fun()
print b
```